# On the proof of the parametric version of the transfinite recursion theorem

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, transfinite-recursion

In the book *Introduction to Set Theory* 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech one can find proofs of the following two theorems:

**Transfinite Recursion Theorem**. Let $G(x)$ be an operation. Then there exists an operation $F(x)$ such that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

**Transfinite Recursion Theorem, Parametric Version**. Let $G(z,x)$ be an operation. Then there exists an operation $F(z,x)$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and all sets $z$.

where $F_z$ denotes the unary operation $F_z(x)=F(z,x)$.

The authors suggest to prove the second theorem by repeating the proof of the first one while carrying $z$ as a parameter troughout.

I was wondering if the following alternative proof is also valid:

---

The proof of the transfinite recursion theorem shows that the property defining $F$ can be written ***explicitly*** from the property defining $G$. Let $P(G)$ denote this property.

Let $G(z,x)$ be an operation. For any fixed $z$ let $G_z$ denote the operation defined by $G_z(x)=G(z,x)$. From the transfinite recursion theorem the property $P(G_z)$ defines an operation $F_z$ for each $z$.

Let $F$ be the operation defined by $F(z,x)=F_z(x)$. Then $F$ satisfies the desired properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proof of the first one doesn't let you carry $z$ as an extra parameter, then no, you can't do what you're suggesting.  A property is described by a *single* formula of the language of set theory.  You can't have a formula varying as a function of a set in the model unless that set is plugged in as an extra parameter in the formula.  The theorem itself is really a theorem *schema* which takes the formula defining the property as input.  The body of the proof then uses this formula to derive another formula to apply an instance of the Replacement axiom schema to.  A proof is only allowed to use *finitely* many axioms of ZF/ZFC.  This includes instantiating an axiom schema (comprehension, replacement) only finitely many times in a proof.  So if the theorem is a schema that takes formulas as 'input', and then plugs the input formulas as subformulas into ZF axiom schemas, you're only allowed to take in finitely many formulas, and plug into axiom schemas finitely many times during a single instantiation of a proof.  If you're familiar with C++ programming, using schemas is kind of like using templates in a C++ program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand the problem. The formula $P_{g_z}(x,y)$ is a single formula that depends on $z,x,y$. The syntax of the formula does not change with $z,x,y$.

Comment: @Alain:  That is exactly what the authors suggested to do - carry $z$ along as an extra parameter.  You're trying to present your argument as an alternative proof.

Comment: Am trying to understand what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: @Alain:  There's nothing wrong with the argument.  It's not an alternative proof.  It's what the authors suggest doing.  If you stop using informal language like "property" or using informal notations like $y=f(x)$ for an operation $f$ and instead revert to using formulas in the language of set theory and substitution of formulas in axiom schemas - you'll see that there is just one proof.

Comment: Ok great then. I agree that my proof follows  closely what the authors suggested. However in the book the authors suggest to repeat the entire proof of the first theorem, while my argument uses the first theorem to deduce the second. I wanted to know if we could deduce the parametric version from the non-parametric version somewhat more "directly".

Comment: @Alain: No, you can't.  But the non-parametric version is artificially constrained by a-priori prohibiting a parameter.  So all they're really saying is "we didn't have to prohibit an additional parameter $z$".

Comment: Ok thanks. If my argument is not  an alternative proof can we call it a "shortcut" since it avoids repeating the proof of the first theorem?

Comment: @Alain:  The problem with your argument is the informal notation '$P_{g_z}(x,y)$'.  If this refers to a formula whose structure depends on the assignment of $z$, you're not allowed to do that.  If it's a single formula containing $z$ as a free parameter, you're not allowed to use it in the first (unparameterized) recursion theorem in the book.  So your argument fails.