# On the definition of ordinal addition using transfinite recursion

Tags: logic, set-theory, transfinite-recursion

Am reading the textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech. In chapter 6 the authors present two versions of the transfinite recursion theorem:

**Transfinite Recursion Theorem**. Let $G$ be an operation. Then there exists an operation $F$ such that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

**Transfinite Recursion Theorem, Parametric Version**. Let $G$ be an operation. Then there exists an operation $F$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and all sets $z$.

Then the authors use the parametric recursion theorem to define addition of two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, i.e. $\alpha+\beta$ is defined as $F(\alpha,\beta)$ where $F$ is defined as in the parametric recursion theorem for some suitable operation $G$.

But I have seen many textbooks (e.g. Enderton p. 232) define ordinal addition $\alpha+\beta$ using the usual non-parametric version. The idea is that for a ***fixed*** $\alpha$ you can define $\alpha+\beta$ as $F_\alpha(\beta)$ where $F_\alpha$ is taken from the non-parametric recursion theorem based on a suitable operation $G_\alpha$ (which depends on $\alpha$).

Basically the first definition is done in "one-shot" while the second definition is done "conditional" on a fixed ordinal $\alpha$.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything **wrong/informal** about the second definition? (Am not an expert in logic).
2. If the second definition is correct, then why should we bother with the parametric version?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio $F_z$ is the operation in one variable defined by $F_z(x)= F(z,x)$.

Comment: The $F$ you defined and $F_\alpha$ defined by the textbooks would have the same definition, so they should be the equivalent approach. I am unsure because it requires checking the proof details for both.

Comment: @HanulJeon I tried to relate the proofs between the two  versions here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4830588/522332 Perhaps you could tell me if am correct?

Comment: The words you used are somewhat nonstandard (e.g., the word "property" is not what logicians use) but your understanding seems close to being correct.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain why the second definition is "incorrect/informal".

Basically one cannot "fix a set $y$" and define a formula $F_y(x)$ with free variable $x$.

What is really happening is that you are defining a formula $F(x,y)$ with two free variables $x,y$.

For more details one can look at the definition of ordinal addition on p. 26 of Kunen's book.

In particular the sentence : "More formally still, the subscripted $\alpha$ becomes an additional free variable
in the formula $F$ occurring in our official explication of Theorem 9.3".

Comment: Of course you can and are allow to "fix" free variables. This is exactly the idea behind parameters. The point is that the functions $F_\alpha(\beta)=\alpha+\beta$ are defined in a uniform way which then provides us with a single definition for the function $F(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha+\beta$. It is true that this is where we need to tread **very** lightly, but this is not a case where problems occur.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your comment.  I got really confused about this lately so perhaps you should answer. Am trying to understand these subtle points: Formally when defining ordinal addition we are applying the parametric version of the recursion theorem right? We cannot inside a proof fix a set $y$ and define a formula $F_y(x)$ and "pretend" its only free variable is $x$ right?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In other words the "uniformity" of $F_\alpha$ comes from the parametric version of the recursion theorem right?

Comment: There are theorems which which parametric proof, but do not result in a uniform formula (e.g. the Reflection Theorem, or even the recursion theorem itself: given any function $G$ we get a function $F$, but it's not somehow uniform, it's a "template"). But in this case, of ordinal arithmetic, the result is in fact uniform. This is coming out of the proof and the way that this is defined.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok.  But I cannot in a proof fix a set $\alpha$, define a function $G_\alpha(x)$, "pretend" its only free variable is $x$, and then apply the non-parametric version of the recursion theorem to obtain $F_\alpha(x)$ right?